# How can I resize the window to fill the full screen height but a specified screen width?

Tags: python, tkinter

Apologies for not being very clear the first time round.
I am looking for a way to specify the size of "fullscreen" for a window. Is there a way for me to do this?
I have a window that opens off fullscreen mode. When I put the window in full screen mode, the bottom of the window goes behind the taskbar. Is there a way that I can avoid this.

Note that I don't know the size of the screen or taskbar beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write:

```
    from tkinter import *
    root = Tk()
    height = root.winfo_screenheight() 
    width = 400      #or whatever you want the width to be
    root.resizable(height = height, width = width)
```

Comment: 1. I don't seem to be able to import this module. I'll work on that. I happened to find another person that had the same problem.

2. I want to be able to edit what it means for a window to be in fullscreen. So when I press the fullscreen button in the top-right corner of the window, the window resized to my required height.

Comment: Just realised you can get the screen dimensions with tkinter